# Нужна помощь с построением графиков matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, график

Всем привет. Задача состоит в том, чтобы построить график температурных условий. У нас есть таблица в exel, в которой наведены данные за целый месяц: время измерения (каждые пол часа = 48 измерений в сутки) и сама температура, дату получаем из названия листа и самого экселя.

Вопрос в том, как мне построить нужный график и при этом строить его по x = время y = температура, но под осью абсцисс выводить дату измерения (каждый день месяца), а не время (по которому строится график).

(на картинке примерно какой график нужен)
[image: примерно какой график нужен]

Код, наверное, тяжело воспринимать, извините :с

```
y = []
x = []
for i in range(len(dataframe['2012-12'].axes[0]) - 1):
#тут мы используем функции для махинаций с экселем и временем, но в итоге мы заполняем список x датой и временем в формате datetime и список y показателями температуры
    x.append(getDateFromStr(getDateFromWorkSheet(i) + "\n" + str(dataframe['2012-12'].iloc[i][1])))
    y.append(dataframe['2012-12'].iloc[i][2])

pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d.%m.%Y\n%H:%M:%S'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
plt.title("Температурні умови") # заголовок
plt.xlabel("Час") # ось абсцисс
plt.ylabel("Температура") # ось ординат
plt.grid()      # включение отображение сетки
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Вы же сами добавили форматтер с минутами: `mdates.DateFormatter('%d.%m.%Y\n%H:%M:%S')`. уберите `\n%H:%M:%S` и посмотрите, что будет.

Comment: @strawdog Да, вы правы, все выглядит значительно лучше, спасибо большое!